# Runtime Complexity of this strings algorithm?

Tags: string, algorithm, big-o

Given strings a and b, I'm trying to understand the big O of the `charDifference` method:

```
public static int charDifference(String first, String second) {
    int steps = 0;
    HashMap<Character, Integer> first_histogram = getFrequencies(first);
    HashMap<Character, Integer> second_histogram = getFrequencies(second);

    Set<Character> first_keys = first_histogram.keySet(); // O(N)
    Set<Character> second_keys = second_histogram.keySet(); // O(N)

    // get first_histogram keys and loop through second_histogram to see what the differences are
        // add differences to steps
    for (char first_char : first_keys){
        int first_count = first_histogram.get(first_char);
        if (second_histogram.containsKey(first_char)){
            int second_count = second_histogram.get(first_char);
            if (first_count > second_count){
                steps += first_count - second_count;
            } else if (first_count < second_count){
                steps += second_count - first_count;
            }
        } else {
            steps += first_count;
        }
    }
    // if this key isn't in second_histogram, then add the count to steps
    // loop through second_histogram keys and if the key isn't in first_histogram, add the count to steps
    for (char second_char : second_keys){
        int second_count = second_histogram.get(second_char);
        if (!(first_histogram.containsKey(second_char))){
            steps += second_count;
        }
    }
    return steps;
}

private static HashMap<Character,Integer> getFrequencies(String str) {
    HashMap<Character, Integer> histogram = new HashMap<Character,Integer>();
    for (int i = 0; i < str.length(); i++){
        char current = str.charAt(i);
        if (histogram.containsKey(current)){
            int count = histogram.get(current);
            histogram.put(current, count+1);
        } else {
            histogram.put(current, 1);
        }
    }
    return histogram;
}
```

I got O(N^2), because I call the getFrequencies function for both strings, and iterate through each set to update the `steps` variable. Is this right? What can I do to decrease the complexity?

Comment: While `O(n^2)` is a correct statement, it is not the best possible estimation for this algorithm.

Comment: This is probably wrong, because the algorithm is fed two sequences and both affect the complexity. Consider marking every line with its complexity, like O(n) or O(m). Then, for a repeated operation, the combined complexity is the product of the loop's complexity by the sum of all complexities inside.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt would n and m represent the lengths of the first and second strings?

Comment: Yes, correct, and your algorithm depends on both their sizes, so both must be considered in the analysis.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt: considering two different string lengths, would the complexity be O( (n^2) + (m^2) )?

Comment: More like O(n + m) as far as I can see. Iterating two sets doesn't give n^2 automatically, if you do one after the other then it is O(2n) = O(n).

Comment: Oh wow, I had that misunderstanding for a while. Thank you @maraca!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To answer your actual questions (not those that I read between the lines!):

1. Your analysis is not correct, as it doesn't even define `N`. Even assuming that was the length of the input, it would still beg the question which input that should be, as already commented, because there are two sequences involved.
2. In order to reduce the upper bound on complexity, you could use a tree-based map instead of the hash map. The former can give you O(log n) for lookups, while the latter requires O(n).

I guess this doesn't help you too much, even though it answers your questions. I'd consider asking what it really is that you are concerned about, but you will have to make up your mind on that first. For example, asking whether something is correct isn't helpful. Explaining your analysis and asking others in what point it isn't correct would be much smarter.